# как в telethon отловить реакцию (telegram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

Хочу написать бота, который будет выдавать призы за то, что человек подписался, оставил коммент и поставил реакцию на посте.
Подписка и коммент - это есть в документации, а вот по поводу реакций сложно.
Подскажите, как можно и можно ли вообще, отловить пользователя который нажал на реакцию(навел на сообщение и поставил смайлик сердечко или класс к примеру)

Кода нет, так как я не знаю, как это делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все реакции на посты в каналах Телеграма анонимны. Не отлавливаются на данный момент вообще никак. То же самое с квизами в канале. А вот если квиз запостить в комментарии к посту - там отловить кто что отвечает вполне реально.